# c# WebBrowser Как при открытии сайтов игнорировать x-frame-options:?

Tags: c#, webbrowser

При открытии сайтов должны игнорироваться x-frame-options (запрет на открытие некоторых страниц в iframe, в браузерах решается установкой мини-плагина)